# Spring REST service.. How do I secure REST calls I am making in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

Spring REST service.. How do I secure REST calls I am making in Spring MVC..

I am working on a Spring MVC web project and we are thinking about moving some of the backend calls to REST service so we can use the same calls on a number of platforms but how do we make them secure?

Comment: yes but then how does the client talk to it.. thanks my issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use HTTPS
2. Use Spring Security with HTTP-header-based authentication

Official examples: https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/tree/master/samples

Comment: Spring Security with HTTP-header-based authentication sounds like what I would like to do but I can't find any good example for service and client side code

Comment: This is exactly what you want to do. Google "spring security basic auth" and you'll get a page full of links to demos and tutorials on how to set it up, like http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-http-basic-authentication-example/ or http://vozis.blogspot.com/2013/02/spring-security-and-http-basic.html

Comment: i been looking at them and code a example but cant get it to work

Comment: @user2428795, I have added examples.

Comment: @Michael-O -- but where is the Security Example with REST SERVICE??

Comment: @ArunKumar, there is nothing special about REST services. They are implemented as regular controllers and views are.

Comment: @Michael-O -- thanks, but that i already know :) . I was looking for the example in the given link that is going to secure a REST service with JSON object where authentication is checked from the DB(some User Details table)and authorization based on user role(defined in DB).

Comment: Did you examine the examples apps in GitHub from SpringSource?

Comment: Here is a guide specific to Spring Security and REST services.
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/5/